# Writing a batch file that will run Coded UI Test 30 times

Tags: batch-file, coded-ui-tests, developer-tools

I wish to run a coded UI test I wrote 30 times. I don't want to do this manualy, and I don't want the test to be inside of a loop.

How can I write a batch file that will activiate MSTest.exe found in Develop command prompt for VS2012?

I tried writing this bat file in order to run my test 3 times, but it doesn't work:

```
MSTest /testcontainer:c:\Users\Desktop\CodedUIFeb2014\CodedUITestProject3\bin\Debug\CodedUITestProject3
.dll /test:T110314

MSTest /testcontainer:c:\Users\Desktop\CodedUIFeb2014\CodedUITestProject3\bin\Debug\CodedUITestProject3
.dll /test:T110314

MSTest /testcontainer:c:\Users\Desktop\CodedUIFeb2014\CodedUITestProject3\bin\Debug\CodedUITestProject3
.dll /test:T110314
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean. Please describe exactly what it did do and what it did not do. To run a thing several times you can use the `for` command (type `help for` at the prompt in a command window). The `for /L ...` may be what you need.

Comment: what about using msbuild script? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb87a184-6589-454b-bf1c-2e82771fc3aa/example-of-msbuild-with-mstest?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 0):

try below syntax.

```
IF %i%==%NOOFITERATION% GOTO END
if exist "%~dp0result.trx" del "%~dp0result.trx"
Mstest /testcontainer:c:\Users\Desktop\CodedUIFeb2014\CodedUITestProject3\bin\Debug\CodedUITestProject3
.dll /resultsfile:result.trx
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP
:end
```

If result .trx file is already present at the execution place it will not initiate the next iteration of test.